# How to evaluate $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\cos t)^{\frac{5}{2}}{\rm d}t$?

Tags: definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

Let $\sqrt{\cos t}=:u$，then $t=\arccos u^2$，${\rm d}t=-\dfrac{2u}{\sqrt{1-u^4}}{\rm d}u$. Therefore

\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\cos t)^{\frac{5}{2}}{\rm d}t&=2\int_0^{1}\frac{u^6}{\sqrt{1-u^4}}{\rm d}u,
\end{align*}

which seems to be the elliptic integral...

## Edit

\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\cos t)^{\frac{5}{2}}{\rm d}t&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^0 t \cos^{\frac{5}{2}}t{\rm d}t\\
&=\frac{1}{2}B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{4}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)}.\\
\end{align*}

Comment: The solution is given by $$\frac{3 \Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}{40 \sqrt{2
   \pi }}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes. WA gives that. How to obtain it?

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

Consider integrating by part. One can obtain
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos ^{\frac{5}{2}}t{\rm d}t&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{\frac{3}{2}}t{\rm d}(\sin t)\\
&=\left[\cos^{\frac{3}{2}}t\sin t\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\frac{3}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{\frac{1}{2}}t\sin^2 t{\rm d}t\\
&=0+\frac{3}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{\frac{1}{2}}t(1-\cos^2 t){\rm d}t\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos ^{\frac{1}{2}}t{\rm d}t-\frac{3}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos ^{\frac{5}{2}}t{\rm d}t.
\end{align*}
Thus
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos ^{\frac{5}{2}}t{\rm d}t=\frac{3}{5}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos ^{\frac{1}{2}}t{\rm d}t=\frac{3}{5}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin ^{\frac{1}{2}}t{\rm d}t.$$

Let $u:=\sin^2 t$. Then ${\rm d} t=\dfrac{{\rm d}u}{2\sin t\cos t}.$ Hence
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin ^{\frac{1}{2}}t{\rm d}t&=\int_0^1\frac{u^{\frac{1}{4}}}{2u^{\frac{1}{2}}(1-u)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\rm d}u\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 u^{-1/4}(1-u)^{-1/2}{\rm d}u\\
&=\frac{1}{2}{\rm B}\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(3/4)\Gamma(1/2)}{2\Gamma(5/4)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(3/4)}{\Gamma(5/4)}.
\end{align*}
It follows that
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos ^{\frac{5}{2}}t{\rm d}t=\frac{3\sqrt{\pi}}{10}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(3/4)}{\Gamma(5/2)}\approx 0.71888\cdots$$